# Incorrect solution to differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

Upon executing the following to solve a differential equation:

```
DSolve[y'[x] == 4 a (-x/2 - y[x]) y[x] - 1/2, y[x], x]
```

I get the following answer

```
{{y[x] -> -(x/4) - 1/(4 a (-x + C[1]))}}
```

However, this doesn't appear to be correct, because when I try and simplify the difference between the left and right hand sides:

```
y0[x_] = -(x/4) - 1/(4 a (-x + constant));
FullSimplify[4 a (-x/2 + 1 - y0[x]) y0[x] - 1/2 - y0'[x]]
```

I get something different from zero:

```
-(1/4) + 1/4 a (-4 + x) x + 1/(-constant + x)
```

I don't believe it is a solution to the differential equation, but I'm not sure why Mathematica thinks it is. Any help in understanding this issue is greatly appreciated.

I'm using version 12.0

Comment: I get a different answer (V13.3.0): https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9TSO.png

Comment: The solution you show is the solution to the ODE `y'[x] == -(1/4) - (a x^2)/4 - 2 a x y[x] - 4 a y[x]^2`, if that's any help in tracking down why you're getting your result.

Answer (score 2):

Don't see any problem in 13.3 on Windows 10.

```
sol = DSolve[y'[x] == 4 a (-x/2 - y[x]) y[x] - 1/2, y, x]
```

> `{{y -> Function[{x}, (-2 a E^(-a x^2) x +  C[1] (1 - Sqrt[a] E^(-a x^2) Sqrt[\[Pi]] x Erfi[Sqrt[a] x]))/( 4 a (E^(-a x^2) + (E^(-a x^2) Sqrt[\[Pi]] C[1] Erfi[Sqrt[a] x])/( 2 Sqrt[a])))]}}`

```
FullSimplify[y'[x] - (4 a (-x/2 - y[x]) y[x] - 1/2) /. sol]
```

> `{0}`

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Mathematica are you using?

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = y'[x] == 4 a (-x/2 - y[x]) y[x] - 1/2;
```

Verification of the solution is easier if you work with a pure function

```
sol = DSolve[eqn, y, x][[1]]

(* {y -> Function[{x}, (-2 a E^(-a x^2) x + 
    C[1] (1 - Sqrt[a] E^(-a x^2) Sqrt[π] x Erfi[Sqrt[a] x]))/(
   4 a (E^(-a x^2) + (E^(-a x^2) Sqrt[π] C[1] Erfi[Sqrt[a] x])/(
      2 Sqrt[a])))]} *)
```

Verifying,

```
eqn /. sol // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Otherwise,

```
sol2 = DSolve[eqn, y[x], x][[1]]

(* {y[x] -> (-2 a E^(-a x^2) x + 
   C[1] (1 - Sqrt[a] E^(-a x^2) Sqrt[π] x Erfi[Sqrt[a] x]))/(
  4 a (E^(-a x^2) + (E^(-a x^2) Sqrt[π] C[1] Erfi[Sqrt[a] x])/(
     2 Sqrt[a])))} *)
```

For this form, simplification of the solution is straightforward

```
sol2 = sol2 // FullSimplify

(* {y[x] -> 1/
   2 (-x + (E^(a x^2) C[1])/(2 a + Sqrt[a] Sqrt[π] C[1] Erfi[Sqrt[a] x]))} *)
```

But verification of the solution is more involved

```
eqn /. Flatten[NestList[D[#, x] &, sol2, 1]] // Simplify

(* True *)
```